# Sending and receiving byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sockets

I'm having some trouble with my socket programming codes. I have a server tcp that receives the password from client, if it's true, the server will send a file back to client to save, else server will send a byte array with the length is 0.

Then the client will receive the byte array and get the length to compare with 0, if byte length = 0, the client will print out "Wrong password", else it will tell you to enter the file name.

The big problem is the server sent byte array with length = 0 when password is wrong, but client receive byte array with length = 1. I do not know how to solve it....:(

Here is my TCPServer code:

```html
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ServerTCP{
 public static void main (String[] args){
  try{
   ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2018);
   System.out.println("\n(*) Server Socket has been created!");
   while(true){
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);
    //Receive information from client
    String mail = sc.nextLine();
    String pass = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Password is: " + pass);
    if(matkhau.equals("passtcp")){
     String filegui = "D:/filename.pdf";
     FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(filegui);
     int lenf = f.available();
     byte b2[] = new byte[lenf];
     f.read(b2);
     f.close();
     os.write(b2);
    }
    else{
     byte b[] = new byte[1];
     int lenb = 0;
     os.write(b);
    }
   }
  }catch(IOException e){
   System.out.println("\n(!)An error occured while creating socket!");
  }
 }
}
```

Here is my client code

```html
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class UdpTcpTest{
 public static void main (String[] args){
  //String matkhau = new String();
  Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
   //Enter TCP Server's ip
   System.out.print("Enter TCP Server's ip: ");
   String ip1 = k.nextLine();
   //Tao socket
   Socket s = new Socket(ip1, 2018);
   InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
   OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
   String mail = "yourmail@test.com";
   String password = "matkhaune";
   //send mail and password to server
   pw.println(mail); pw.flush();
   pw.println(password); pw.flush();
   //receive information
   byte brecv[] = new byte[60000];
   int lenfile = is.read(brecv);
   System.out.println("Length = " + lenfile);
   if(lenfile <= 1){
    System.out.println("Wrong password! Length = " + lenfile);
   }
   else{
    //Save file
    System.out.print("Enter file name to save: ");
    String filenamed = k.nextLine();
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(filenamed);
    f.write(brecv, 0, lenfile);
    f.close();
    System.out.println("Saving Scuccess!");
    s.close();
   }
  }catch(IOException e){
   System.out.println("Error while excuting!");
  }
  
 }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. The server is sending a byte array of length 1.  It is not possible to send zero bytes and have that detected by the client because, well, nothing gets sent.  You must change your protocol to include an actual "invalid password" message.

Comment: So could i change the code "int lenb = 1" to fix this problem?

Comment: `lenb` is not doing anything. You don't refer to it anywhere and it goes out of scope immediately.  You could remove that entire statement and nothing would change.  You must change the way your server signals to the client that the password was invalid.  There must be actual data transmitted that carries that message.

Comment: alright, i got that. so if i remove lenb, so when the password is wrong, server will send a statement about invalid password, and how client know that isn't a file?

Comment: That is what is known as a "protocol".  An agreed  set of messages that allow a server and client to exchange data (the file) but also metadata ("here comes a file", or "oops, the password was bad").  For a simple but effective protocol look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol  FTP was designed a _long_ time ago and is sort of deprecated today but understanding it will let you design a much simpler version for yourself.

Comment: Because of my mind is when the password wrong, the server will send the byte array with length = 0 to client, so that client can compare byte's length received to print out the "wrong password". unless the server will send the data that read from file and send to client, so that the length will larger than 1....Hope you can understand :D

Comment: To repeat what @JimGarrison is telling you, the server does not and cannot send a byte array of length zero. Your code is sending a byte array of length one, and that is the minimum that can be sent.

Comment: alright, thank you. I understood :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having some trouble with my socket programming codes. I have a server tcp that receives the password from client, if it's true, the server will send a file back to client to save, else server will send a byte array with the length is 0.

Impossible.

> Then the client will receive the byte array and get the length to compare with 0, if byte length = 0, the client will print out "Wrong password", else it will tell you to enter the file name.

Impossible. You will have to redesign your protocol. You can't send a byte array of zero length over TCP. The minimum is one byte.

> The big problem is the server sent byte array with length = 0 when password is wrong

No it didn't. It sent a byte array with length = 1:

```
byte b[] = new byte[1]; // Here is your byte array of length 1
int lenb = 0;  // This is unused. Delete.
os.write(b);   // Here you are sending the entire byte array
```

> but client receive byte array with length = 1.

That is correct.

> I do not know how to solve it....:(

There is nothing here to solve. Your code is working as designed. You just need to adjust your client to test for a 1-byte receive instead of an impossible zero-byte receive:

```
int lenfile = is.read(brecv);
System.out.println("Length = " + lenfile);
if(lenfile == 1){
```